# LED strip negative wire connected from the end

Tags: led, wiring

Recently I ordered some christmas led ligths from China, and I wanted to mess with it a bit (dimming, cutting it to parts), and i noticed that it is wired differently than I expected.

It seems that the negative wire is carried all the way to the last LED and only then it is connected to each one of them one by one, while the positive, is connected from the source side.
[image: led lights]
[image: led wiring]

Is there any advantage, on the electrical side, to do this instead of just going straight like this:
[image: led wiring]

Or maybe the only benefit is in toughness.

Comment: Electrially no, but that factory might already have a similar product with blinking/running lights using three wires and it was easier to adapt that to this simplyle constant on light string. With this, the end should be slightly brighter than the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you redraw your LED diagram to show the resistance of the wires (forget about the exact values, or the fact that the diodes shown are not LEDs, that's not important)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgsySs.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

then you will see that for a long string, if you powered them with both terminals at the D1 end, D1 would be bright, and the rest would get progressively dimmer.

If you power the string at opposite ends, the voltage drops across the sections of wire are equalised, and the LEDs get the same voltage. Each LED sees the same length of wire, the same resistance.

Comment: That makes sense. Did not thought about that. Thanks!

Comment: +1 Just to add. Each LED current now sees 4 hypothetical resistors. Very good explanation